# jQuery: Adding a destroy method to plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I've created a plugin which I need to be able to unbind and rebind at will. How can I 
package this within a method in my plugin so that it can be called at will?

My plugin is like so:

```
 (function($) {
     $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
            .................
            .................
            .................
            .................
            .................
            .................
      }; 
})( jQuery );
```

And called like...

```
$('#selector').myPlugin();
```

Edit: Basically, I want to add a destroy method to my plugin

Answer (score 2):

Well somthing like that:

```
delete $.fn.MyPlugin;
```

Optionally you can write destroy method into your plugin e.g.:

```
destroy: function() {
    this._destroy(); //or this.delete; depends on jQuery version
    this.element.unbind( this.eventNamespace )
    this.bindings.unbind( this.eventNamespace );
    //this.hoverable.removeClass( "hover state" );
    //this.focusable.removeClass( "focus state" );
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to add a destroy method to my plugin so I can manually unbind all my handlers to the appropriate selectors

Comment: Thanks. How do I structure this within my current plugin? Does it go within the plugin function or outside of it?

Comment: @Fraser just call your plugin with parameter ('destroy'); eg:

    $('selector').MyPlugin('destroy');

Comment: Any where do I place the destroy: function(){...} within the plugin it's self?

Comment: You can see an example in jQuery UI.js ;)